# Check for active session before loading complete navigation in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a welcome controller with index function:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates\header');      
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        $this->load->view('templates\footer');
    }
```

Header view code goes like following:

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>">
                    Test App
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

It works perfectly fine so far.
I also want to add following code in my navigation bar (with in header tags) as a menu items but only if the user session is active. So if a user is logged in than only he/she should be able to see the menu item else the user should only see a navbar with brand name "Test App".

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome') ?>"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/logout') ?>"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I also have a helper which check and return true or false if the user is logged in or not and i am using it inside the controller. I am not comfortable using that inside the view because than i have to echo the menu items and adjust a lot of double/single quotes to make that work. Is there a neat way to do this ?

Code for login helper:

```
function is_logged_in() {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $user = $CI->session->userdata('username');
    if ( !isset($user) )
    {
        return false; 
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can choose what to display according to the user session from controller.

For example:

```
 if($this->session->userdata('username')<>NULL){ 
    $data['logged_in'] = 1;
 }else{
    $data['logged_in'] = 0;
 }
 $this->load->view('templates\header',$data);
```

In view:

```
   if($logged_in==1){
      //header with logged in options
     }else{
      //header with normal options.
      }
```

Comment: Thanks. In order to do this i need to keep two different views with part common code. I mean repeating slight part of code in two different views. It doesn't look like much but is it the correct way.

Comment: @Saurabh Try this way, changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `session_status()`?

On its [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php#113468) one of the users posted in comments universal function for checking if session is started:

```
<?php
/**
* @return bool
*/
function is_session_started()
{
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// Example
if ( is_session_started() === FALSE ) session_start();
?>
```